# Why VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1 not shown in Network Connection?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, connection, vmware-workstation

VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1, VMnet8 and Bluetooth do not show up in Network Connection's. Only the Wireless Network Adapter is shown! What could be the reason for this?

Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm that it is not "Disabled" ?
Network >> Change Adapter Settings

Comment: Not shown that Enable it!

Comment: after delete and add VMnet1 and VMnet2 now is shown but can not enable it